# Debug Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been attempting to debug Apache Tomcat by defining the setenv.sh. These are contents of the file.

```
export JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA as the IDE.

When I place the setenv.sh file in bin folder, every time the connection is made successfully to port 8000 but I find that on some attempts the debug points are met but sometimes they don't. When I stop the debugger the server never starts up. I am using `sh bin/catalina.sh jpda start` command. The logs do not work in such attempts as well.

But sh bin/catalina.sh start work perfectly fine on every attempt.

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: what happens if you use `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`  be aware of **suspend=n**

Comment: Well I did not try it that way since that does not reach any point at all so I have no idea... simple server startups as mentioned using sh bin/catalina.sh start works fine

Answer (score 0):

> on some attempts the debug points are met but sometimes they don't

I believe you mean `break points`. Check if you are using the same version of the sources as the compiled tomcat. It's normal (and expected) to have mismatches between versions. Also make sure you don't accidentally reformat the sources.

> When I stop the debugger the server never starts up

The application does not start because you have `suspend=y`flag, which means "wait for debugger to attach". Change that to `suspend=n` and theapplication will start without debugger.

PS: When you want to debug - start the server with `catalina.sh jpda start`. Without the **jpda** parameter the JVM won't start in debug mode

Comment: But the problem is how do we suspend it... my intention is to debug the code so I need it to suspend. Please pardon me I am relatively new to debugging related stuff. I am using the matching versions as well.

Comment: Hi I restarted my machine and performed a new maven build. This time it worked fine. I believe this is an issue related to the machine I am using... I am not quite sure though. Every single server run worked with suspension on as well. I managed to carry out all the debugging as well.